# Haskell: Sum of the occurrences of each char from a string A in a string B

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold

Say that I have two strings, how can I get the sum of the occurrences of each char in string A in string B?

For exemple, how can I know, in the string someString: the numbers of a + the numbers of b ... + the number of f?

```
sumOccurrencesOfCharsInString :: String -> String -> Int
sumOccurrencesOfCharsInString str1 str2 = ?

-- evaluating sumOccurrencesOfCharsInString someString notes should return 3+0+3+0+5+0+1= 12
someString = "Evaluating sumOccurrencesOfCharsInString someString notes would return 12"

notes = "abcdefg"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a list comprehension:

```
 length [ s | s <- someString, s `elem` notes]
```

Comment: And consider using a set instead of a list for `notes` to get from `O(nm)` to `O(n lg m)`.

Answer (score 3):

As a first attempt, this should do the trick:

```
countChars              ::  Char -> String -> Int
countChars c            =   length . filter (== c)

sumOccurrences          ::  String -> String -> Int
sumOccurrences as bs    =   sum [countChars a bs | a <- as]
```